# Screen sharing cannot be turned on in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, vnc

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and with Vino 3.22 installed. I'm trying to enable Screen Sharing through Settings -> *Sharing* -> *Screen Sharing*, but the button to turn it on is grayed out. How can I enable this button to activate Screen Sharing?

Grayed out Screen Sharing button:

[image: screenshot of greyed out Screen Sharing button]

Comment: Does the option become available if you connect to a wired (ethernet) network?

Comment: While connected to Mobile Broadband it remains disabled. While Connected to a Corporate Wifi it remains disabled. BUT ... when connecting to Wifi using personal phone hotspot, it does become enabled.

Comment: can you check what is in tail -f /var/sys/log ? Especially check for the NetworkManager messages as there is this known bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1676547